# Add some space after each character string in the output

Tags: text, header, fortran

I want to write headers in a file, but when I do the following:

```
write(30,*) 'apple', 'ball', 'cat'
write(30,*) 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'
```

I get output header as:

```
appleballcat               
ababab
```

but I need:

```
apple ball cat         
a b a b a b
```

How to do this?

Comment: Please take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Why don't you just write `write(30,*) "apple ball cat"`? Please also make a more specific title for your queastion.

Comment: Please pay extra attention to the code you present and the output given.  I can't imagine many compilers would choose to tell you about a dog just because you ask about an apple, a ball and a cat.

Comment: @SCh I have changed the title of the question a bit (so that the intention becomes clearer), but please feel free to roll it back if it does not match your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ' a ' to get appace after the a. Don't do it with b or else you'll get 2 spaces.  Do the same for apple and cat. Your using 'apple' but you should use ' apple '.

Comment: I have no idea what does this mean and what kind of code you may have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to add one space after each "word", for example...

```
!! no space may be given between words
write(30,*) 'apple', 'ball', 'cat'
write(30,*) 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'

!! "*" indicates an unlimited repeat count   
write(30,'(*(A,1X))') 'apple', 'ball', 'cat'
write(30,'(*(A,1X))') 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'

!! ":" terminates format control if there are no more items in the I/O list    
write(30,'(*(A : 1X))') 'apple', 'ball', 'cat'
write(30,'(*(A : 1X))') 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'

!! for old compilers (1000 is some large number)    
write(30,'(1000(A,1X))') 'apple', 'ball', 'cat'
write(30,'(1000(A,1X))') 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'
```

which gives (with gfortran-8.2)

```
 appleballcat
 ababab
apple ball cat
a b a b a b
apple ball cat
a b a b a b
apple ball cat
a b a b a b
```

They may be useful for printing words contained in character arrays etc. More details can be found, for example, in a [Format Specifications](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-format-specifications) page.